# After I reinstalled Android Studio Giraffe, I can no longer run my project on my real devices

Tags: android, android-studio, ubuntu, android-virtual-device

I updated the Ubuntu version on my laptop to 22.04 from 20.04 and had to reinstall Android Studio. The day before, I was happily developing away but now when I connect the USB cable to the device (a Samsung Tab A), nothing happens. I tried the suggestions from Google found [here](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-connect-device#5), but that didn't help. Any ideas? My AVDs all disappeared, too.

Update: The USB cable wasn't connected to the laptop. How embarassing!

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are a lot of posts about Andorid/USB problems on Linux and how to diagnose them.

Comment: @Robert I think I've tried everything I've found on this site.

Comment: Which version of Android are you using? I guess Samsung Tab A supports Android 11 and you can try wi-fi debugging
Have you checked this link? https://developer.android.com/tools/adb#connect-to-a-device-over-wi-fi

Comment: @BerkBerber Please see update to my post: I had connected an external drive to the USB port I normally use for connecting to my real devices. D'Oh!